# Tool to develop multi-platform games

Tags: flash, air, unity-game-engine

I need to develop a game that runs on Android/Iphone and on Facebook (an app). I saw Unity 3d, but it has a beta version (not stable) that exports to Flash Player. What the best tool that will do the job?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It really depends on what sort of game you're creating.

Unity3D is really worth another look if you're creating a 3D game. Others have used the Unity3d browser plugin successfully to make facebook games. Example, "Off-Road Velociraptor Safari"

Also, flash and adobe air could also be on the table for consideration

"Adobe Flash Professional CS5.5 lets you publish your ActionScript 3 projects to run as native apps on iOS." - http://www.adobe.com/devnet/logged_in/abansod_iphone.html

"Android™ devices: Download from the Android Market directly from your Android device.
iOS devices: AIR apps for iOS install a "captive" version of Adobe AIR; therefore, users do not install a dedicated version of AIR." - http://www.adobe.com/products/air/faq.html